# Recommended RPG game that can be used to learn game Modding?

Tags: mmo, level-design, modding, rpg

I would like to learn game development via game modding. RPG/MMORPG is one of my favorite genres. Could someone recommend me a good and recent ( I would like to play the game as well) game to learn game modding. Something with the likes of Neverwinternights 2.

Thank you very much for the responses. Appreciate it.

Comment: What's wrong with NWN2?

Comment: Nothing wrong with NWN2, I've tried it a while back (played it and modded a abit and its one of my favorite games). The thing is i'd like to learn level-design as well as programming and I prefer a game that still has lots of players so that I could get feedback from. Plus i'd like to play something new as well ;)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For RPGs, you might look at:

- [Elder Scrolls: Skyrim](http://www.rarityguide.com/articles/articles/1412/1/Skyrim-Creation-Kit-Tutorial-How-to-Install-the-Skyrim-Creation-Kit/Page1.html)
- [Elder Scrolls: Oblivion Construction Wiki](http://cs.elderscrolls.com/constwiki/index.php/Main_Page)
- [Elder Scrolls: Oblivion, Modding Faq](http://cs.elderscrolls.com/constwiki/index.php/Oblivion_Mods_FAQ)
- [Mount and Blade Mod Repository](http://www.mbrepository.com/)

M&B is more recent than Oblivion, but both are still played (and worth playing). For MMOs, Edward83's recommendation of Lua is good, however - for World of Warcraft, you would only be using Lua to write add-ons, not full mods.

To clarify, when you make a mod for a game like Oblivion or Neverwinter Nights, you're actually changing the full game experience - you could make a science-fiction version of Oblivion, for instance. But with Warcraft/Lua, all you would be doing is making changes to the *interface*, not the game itself. You couldn't, say, add a new *item* to Warcraft, or change the skins to be Klingons.

You can do a lot of cool things in WoW addons (and you can learn programming with Lua), but if you're interested in eventually making a full *game* - it's not quite the same as developing a *mod*.

Comment: +1 for the Oblivion Construction Pack, and also the Fallout 3 G.E.C.K (same thing, just the modkit is for Fallout 3 since Bethesda did both). They are really easy to get started on, and they definitely aren't lacking in what you can actually do.

Comment: Thank you very much, looks like a good place to start learning with wiki's,guide's n all. Will probably try it soon or should I wait for next Elder Scrolls to come out next year? mmmm

Comment: @Stucko, depends, how soon did you want to start learning game development? :) If you have the time, start now - even if the next release has differences, the basic concepts should be similar. There's no time like the present...

Answer (score 7):

In addition to the games Cyclops mentioned, *Fallout 3* and *Fallout: New Vegas* use the Oblivion engine and are highly moddable.

Answer (score 7):

Elder Scrolls is a great start, but I found the best RPG engine to get people really started modding is the Neverwinter Nights Aurora engine, simply because they have the largest collection of public tools for modding, and you can really get a feel for what it feels like to work on a game with their tools.

http://nwn.bioware.com/developers/

Comment: I have extensive experience modding and authoring for this engine and I can attest that is it very flexible and easy to work with. Do not underestimate the usefulness of the tile-based terrain: it makes everything from asset creation to content creation to scripting quite a bit easier. It has aged a bit though, it does not look as snazzy as the new kids on the block. I would stay away from the NWN2 engine: it's a mess. I have not checked out the Dragon Age toolset as of yet. It is probably your best bet right now.

Answer (score 4):

World of Warcraft supports [scripting on Lua](http://www.wowwiki.com/Lua). Is it what you need?

Also check Mods for Games [tutorials](http://www.moddb.com/tutorials) and [engines](http://www.moddb.com/engines);

Comment: I think he's looking to actually change the game; WoW allows you to customize your interface and to build little add-on programs to run within WoW, but you're not actually allowed to add anything or change how anything in the game works.

Comment: Yes, I'm actually looking at building levels/quests/AI but thanks Edward83 for giving the link to http://www.moddb.com, very informative site.

Answer (score 4):

Dragon Age: Origins includes the toolset for modding.  Recently, Bioware released the [Ultimate Edition](http://amzn.to/gxGLP9) with all of the DLC up to this point.  I think this would satisfy your requirements of a good, modern game that can be modded.

Answer (score 4):

The Garden of Eden creation kit for FallOut 3 is pretty cool.

http://fallout.bethsoft.com/eng/downloads/geck.html